# Why my email sending doesn't work on deployed website but it works on my localhost?

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, gmail

Until some weeks, my email would send perfectly from the website I have created for a cousin's business, but now she told me her customers get this error every time they try to make an appointment.

Now I have started to debug it, I've checked that the gmail I am using for sending is allowing every application to access it, I have checked again the spring boot application properties, etc. When testing it on my localhost it sends the email, but on the deployed website it gives the error in the picture below... Again, two months ago when I did the last check, it worked fine. And it still works fine, but just on my localhost.

This is how my application properties looks like:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=..
spring.mail.password=..
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

And this is a screenshot with the error everyone gets (the webiste is deployed with heroku):[image: the thing]

Thank you!

Comment: `javax.mail.AuthenticationException` says the error. Not to mention the "please login through your browser", so it's security related. Are you trying to use a regular GMail account for the mail sending?

Comment: yes, a regular gmail which gives permission to all apps. But why do I get this error now? Until some months ago it worked, and is still does work but just on my localhost...

Comment: Because Google has a lot of security checks. I once woke up to an SMS telling me someone had tried to login to my Google account in Bolivia, which was blocked since it didn't fit into my usage profile. Two-Factor Authentication can affect this also, if you have it enabled.

Comment: So odd, I get emails on that email adress that someone from Ireland Dublin is doing bad stuff :)) But what should I change more? Is there a particular setting besides the one for less secure app access that should modify? That two factor is turned off to me

Comment: Have you looked at the support link in the exception?

Comment: It redirects me to my gmail account settings, but not to the one I used in the website but to the one I am logged in on my computer

Comment: Well, if you could proxy your traffic through your server, you could login via browser through it. I'd wager it's [captcha](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/11959249?hl=en). You might want to enable 2FA, and then add the application specific password to your system.

Comment: Thank you so much! Please make it an answer so that I can upvote it <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, there's an `AuthenticationException` and the error message is asking to log in through the browser.

Since 2FA is off, the most likely reason is that they want to show a CAPTCHA, which would need human interaction. The [link](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/11959249?hl=en) I found suggests that by visiting https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha on the target account would allow you to clear the captcha manually, and then it would work.

However I'm not convinced that clearing the captcha manually is enough, since it might come back at any time. It seems the proper way to go would be through enabling 2FA, and using [application specific passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to Pass Username(Gmail Id) and Gmail Mail APi Generated Password
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```